# Spring Security @PreAuthorize breaks Jersey @Context UriInfo injection

Tags: java, groovy, spring-security, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a problem with a Jersey/Spring RESTful web application I'm building. I want to use the @PreAuthorize annotation to secure my endpoints. However, I need to have access to the UriInfo because I do work with the query parameters.

Everything works fine until I secure the method, then suddenly my UriInfo is null. I'm fairly certain this has to do with how @PreAuthorize is causing things to be scoped - no longer at the request level.

```
@Component
@Path("/equipment")
public class Equipment
{
    @Context 
    UriInfo ui;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANALYST', 'ROLE_DEVELOPER')")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public def list() {
        println ui
        return [:]
    }

}
```

The simple class below will print "null".

If you remove the @PreAuthorize annotation, you get the expected result - org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.UriInfoInjectee@23b21e3

Based on things I've seen in other questions, let me say in advance my application context already has this line:

`<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>`

and the authorization part is working perfectly. It's just the injection of UriInfo that's failing.

I am using Spring 3.1.4 and Jersey 2.3. Code provided is in Groovy but that's not the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I may be off base with the thought that it's bean scope causing the problem. I used @Scope("request") and confirmed with a println that I get a new instance of Equipment with every request but UriInfo is still null. Tried it as session scope, same instance, still null. I may just be barking up the wrong tree here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've come up with a solution that gets me around my problem and I'm leaving it here for posterity. The answer doesn't satisfy the "why" of it all, but it does get my application working and it's not really a munge.

Instead of injecting UriInfo at the class level, I inject it at the method level. I got the idea from [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/twbs_jaxrs_contextobjects_uri.html). Their explanation is that if a method signature might get modified, inject it there. I guess Spring Security is doing that, but I don't understand why that would break something injected at the class level.

Working code for posterity:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANALYST', 'ROLE_DEVELOPER')")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public def list(@Context UriInfo ui) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did You try to investigate this problem more (or ask Spring Security developers about that)? I have the same problem and I cannot inject UriInfo at method level because of some other requirements.

Comment: @pWoz Sorry this reply is late, but no I didn't. We wound up dropping Groovy for Clojure and Jersey for Compojure.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this same issue and been fighting with it for a couple of weeks now.  The suggested workaround isn't practical for my uses though.

Another workaround I've seen suggested is to move the @PreAuthorize annotation down to the service layer (or some other application layer) instead of using it directly on the REST resource.  That solution isn't practical for me either, but thought I'd add it as another possibility.

Comment: I filed a bug about this issue against Jersey as well (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2919), although it could be a spring or spring-security issue.